# PrintWritter: How to check if output file exists?

Tags: java, printf, printwriter

Language: java
IDE: Visual Studio Code
My program reads a file ( used FileReader and Scanner) and writes it, formatted, to a new file (used FileWritter, PrintWritter, and printf). How do I test that the new file exists, since the program compiles but doesn't print anything to the terminal.

Comment: `if (new File("MyFileName.txt").exists()) { System.out.println("Yippee"); }`

Comment: See also Files.exist(Path, LinkOption...).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the list of files in the directory and then check if your new file name exist in the list

```
    Set<String> filesPresent = Stream.of(new File(PathOfFilesCreated).listFiles())
                  .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
                  .map(File::getName)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(filesPresent.contains(newFileName));
```